# On idle time process workingset is trimmed on window7 x64

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection

In my dotnet (C#) application when application is running the private workingset of the process goes up to 250MB size. And when application is idle the workingset memory goes down to 6MB of size (displayed in task manager).

But the problem is that when you activate the application again workingset memory goes up but application response is very slow and sluggish. The operation normally takes 1or2 seconds now takes 10secs.

Any solution to this problem is appreciated.

Environment: VS2010 with dotnet 4.0 on Windows7 x64 with 4GB RAM. System managed pagefile is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more (a lot more) about your application this is impossible to answer. Can I suggest you provide details of what your application does and the results of any testing you have done yourself.